# How to retrieve the instantaneous (last) state of the keyboard with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard, key

I have posted the same issue on github because I am not sure whether this is a pygame issue or me doing something wrong: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/1619

I am trying to use pygame in a project where I must get the current instantaneous state of the keyboard. According to https://devdocs.io/pygame/ref/key#pygame.key.get_pressed , the get_pressed() function should do this, however apparently it does not: it seems to return the first event frame it didn't process instead of the last one.

Showing this is this code snippet:

```py
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))

i = 0
while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    print(f"iter:{i}")
    # print(f"events:{events}")
    print(f"keys[pygame.K_a]:{keys[pygame.K_a]}")
    time.sleep(5.0)
    i = i + 1
```

If during, let's say, the sleep() of iteration 5, I press and release twice the 'a' key (which by the way seems to be 'q' on my French keyboard), the following happens:

```sh
iter:5
keys[pygame.K_a]:0
iter:6
keys[pygame.K_a]:0
iter:7
keys[pygame.K_a]:1
iter:8
keys[pygame.K_a]:0
iter:9
keys[pygame.K_a]:1
iter:10
keys[pygame.K_a]:0
iter:11
keys[pygame.K_a]:0
```

I would expect to see only zeroes here, or just one '1' at iteration 6 if I was still pressing 'a' at the end of sleep().

Am I doing something wrong? And if so, can you help me retrieve the current state of the keyboard instead, please? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `time.sleep()`.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from your output if you were or were not pressing a key at the time. I am unable to replicate locally

Comment: @Kingsley : time.sleep() is here to replicate the setting where you press and release several time a key between two calls to pygame.key.get_pressed().

Comment: @IainShelvington : You can't replicate? In this example I was pressing and releasing the 'a' key twice when time.sleep() was executed right before iteration 6. I get this behavior consistently on my machine.

Comment: @YannBouteiller I added some logging for keydown/up events and this is my log https://justpaste.it/2vbzy

Comment: @IainShelvington very strange... Your output looks exactly like what I expect but I used your code and got the following: https://justpaste.it/42f3l My python version is 3.7.3

Comment: @YannBouteiller from your log it appears that `get_pressed` is working as expected. There don't appear to be any KEYDOWN/KEYUP events before iter1 though as you said, maybe there is something strange going on with your keyboard?

Comment: @IainShelvington I don't think it is related to the keyboard because what consistently happens on my machine is that the first call to `get_pressed` doesn't return anything, and then each call returns one single event. I would expect it to work more like in your logs where all the events are retrieved in one single call to `get_event`

Comment: Which OS are you using and which version of SDL?

Comment: @IainShelvington the OS is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and the SDL installed versions are libsdl1.2debian:amd64 (1.2.15+dfsg2-0.1) and libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.3) apparently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in 1.9.6

Version 2.0.0 corrects it.